# AngularJS Redraw issue? Chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Super new to AngularJS so please be patient with me :)

We're using it to poll our API for updates while we process a repository (and after).  On one particular page the data is loaded but not drawn to the screen.  Highlighting the content, or resizing the browser causes a redraw and shows all angular values that weren't there a moment ago!  Latest Chrome!

**Just look:**  Everything starts at "0" or "-" but highlighting the page reveals "Optimized Images" and "Filesize Savings" content changes.

**Live example:**
MAY REQUIRE YOU HIT REFRESH TO HAVE THE ANGULAR DRAW FAIL

REQUIRES CHROME ~ Version 31.0.1650.63 m
It works on Firefox!?!
http://crusher.io/repo/alhertz/didthesaintswin/63f49d36e709dea172fe7e4bbacbcfd834f9a642

This appears to be very similar to this question, but there is no nested controller issue I can detect: [Update page contents after GET request in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738230/update-page-contents-after-get-request-in-angularjs)

When I try to add a `$scope.$apply()` I get this error: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope:inprog?p0=$apply

This is the relevant code in the angular controller (coffeescript):

```
  do poll = ->
    $http.get("#{$location.absUrl()}/poll.json").success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      if $scope.continuePolling
        #console.log("still polling #{$location.absUrl()}")
        $scope.data = data
        $scope.TotalOptimizedImage = $scope.CalcTotalOptimizedImage(data.images)
        $scope.TotalImgSize = $scope.CalcTotalImgSize(data.images)
        $scope.SavedImgSize = $scope.CalcSavedImgSize(data.images)
        $scope.TotalSavings = ($scope.TotalImgSize - $scope.SavedImgSize + 0)
        $timeout(poll, 10000)
    )
```

Really not sure how to break this apart for fixing.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try and recreate the problem inside a plunker of jsfiddle? Would be much easier to assist then.

Comment: @gantman, Did the answer below help you solve the issue?

Comment: no, it did not :(  It's still an issue, but I've got a workaround in place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call `$scope.apply` inside the callback to the http.get.  The reason is that the callback will happen outside the controller digest.  Sorry I'm not adept at coffee script but something like this:

```
 $http.get("#{$location.absUrl()}/poll.json").success((data, status, headers, config) 
  if $scope.continuePolling
    $scope.$apply(function() {  // wrap the stuff you want to update in the $scope.$apply
    #console.log("still polling #{$location.absUrl()}")
    $scope.data = data
    $scope.TotalOptimizedImage = $scope.CalcTotalOptimizedImage(data.images)
    $scope.TotalImgSize = $scope.CalcTotalImgSize(data.images)
    $scope.SavedImgSize = $scope.CalcSavedImgSize(data.images)
    $scope.TotalSavings = ($scope.TotalImgSize - $scope.SavedImgSize + 0)
  });
    $timeout(poll, 10000)
)
```

I would suggest that you use a [safeApply](https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply) function and there is a great timeFunctions service that might help you with the polling that I've used quite successfully in a couple projects. You can find it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237070/using-setinterval-in-angularjs-factory).